# Statechart for a fluid library equipment?

Tags: fluid, anylogic

I am trying to model a Dairy factory in Anylogic.
I'd like to program the fact that a tank need to be cleaned after each batch.
I was thinking to use a statechart to model that, but as far as i have looked, it seems that tanks, pipeline, etc... can't have a statechart unlike "normal" agents.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: normal tank or process tank?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

[image: structure]

In the tank there is an action "on new batch at input"... You will put the following code there:

```
valve.close(); //close the valve to clean the tank
create_cleanTank(5);//assuming your cleaning time is 5 time units..
```

In the dynamic event you will put the following code:

```
valve.open(); //the tank is cleaned, so you can open the valve now.
```